# Openxava Filter data based on logged user

Tags: filter, openxava

As the title above, I wish to get seperated data from logged in user only. For instance, in either simultaneously or non-simultaneously, user1 loads his/her own data while user2 loads his/her own data, which both users do not share the same data output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The codes below are the solution for getting url parameter value and filtering user data.

Activity.java

```
    ...

    @Hidden
    @ReadOnly
    @OnChange(GetParameterValueAction.class)
    @Column(name="AKA_LOC_ID", length=10)
    private String locId;

    ...

    Getters and Setters
```

GetParameterValueAction.java

```
...

public class GetParameterValueAction extends OnChangePropertyBaseAction {

    @Override
    public void execute() throws Exception {

        String locId = getRequest().getParameter("LocId");

        getView().setValue("locId", locId);

    }

}
```

OnEachRequestFilteredTabAction.java

```
...

public class OnEachRequestFilteredTabAction extends BaseAction{

    @Inject @Named("application_locId")
    private String locId;

    @Inject
    private Tab tab;

    @Override
    public void execute() throws Exception {
        locId = getRequest().getParameter("LocId");
        if (!Is.empty(locId)) tab.setBaseCondition("${locId}='" + locId + "'");
        else tab.setBaseCondition("${locId}='ERROR'");
    }

    public String getLocId() {
        return locId;
    }

    public void setLocId(String locId) {
        this.locId = locId;
    }

    public Tab getTab() {
        return tab;
    }

    public void setTab(Tab tab) {
        this.tab = tab;
    }



    }
```

controllers.xml

```
<?xml version = "1.0" encoding = "ISO-8859-1"?>
<!DOCTYPE controllers SYSTEM "dtds/controllers.dtd">

<controllers>

   <object name="application_locId" class="java.lang.String" scope="global"/>
   <controller name="DataAccessControl">
        <action name="initTab" 
            hidden="true" 
            on-each-request="true" 
            mode="list" 
            class="org.survey.actions.OnEachRequestFilteredTabAction" />
    </controller>

</controllers>
```

application.xml

```
<?xml version = "1.0" encoding = "ISO-8859-1"?>
<!DOCTYPE application SYSTEM "dtds/application.dtd">
<application name="____"> //your application/folder name 

    <module name="Activity">
        <model name="Activity"/>
        <controller name="Activity"/>
        <controller name="DataAccessControl"/>
    </module>

</application>
```